# cannot convert data to upper case using `request.getParameter`

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%String dest = request.getParameter("destination").toUpperCase();%>
```

Hello...

I got a little bit problem here. I am using the above code to get value from form. When use the code without `toUpperCase()`, it was a success. But, when I add `toUpperCase()` I got `HTTP Status 500 - An exception occured processing JSP page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get value `null` from `request.getParameter("destination")`, apply  `toUpperCase()` to a `null` value gives an error.
Try to do like this:

```
 <%String dest = request.getParameter("destination");
   if(dest!=null){
      dest = dest.toUpperCase();
    }
   %>
```

> The request.getParameter() returns String value or a null value from client.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, `request.getParameter("destination")` is returning `null` in your code, which would be why it's throwing an error. If the parameter is not found, then `null` is returned, otherwise a `String` is returned.

So you'll want to verify that it's not null

```
<% String dest = request.getParameter("destination");

if(dest != null) {
    dest = dest.toUpperCase();
}
%>
```